# How to assign dynamic variables to CSS content in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js

Apologies if this shows how much of a novice I am, but I'd like to know more about dynamic variables and CSS in Vue. I'd like to create a system where each time a button is pressed, the letters of the button label become further apart.

Inside a component is it possible to use a counter script such as:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Counter', 
    data() {
      return {
        count: 3,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      intrement() {
        this.count += 1;
      }
    }
  } 
</script>
```

And then use the count integer value to change CSS text spacing for example?
So that in the template, I could use:

```html
<template>
  <header>
    <div>
      <button class="header_button" style="letter-spacing: `v-bind(count) + ch`;">MYBUTTON</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

I appreciate this is a strange and specific example, but if anyone could give me some feedback as to why this doesn't work, as well as suggestions on how I could achieve this I'd be super appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you can directly use the following

```html
<button :style="`letter-spacing: ${count}ch;`">
```

Here is [a playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpdUctOwzAQ/JWVhQSINhYHLm5aCTgDl3JAskTdZNu4ih+yNwVU5d9xkiZFnLwz3sfs7Ik9ep8dG2SC5bEI2tNKWgD89i4QlLhTTU1w6jgAqwwKuH52jSUM1zMY6FKRurkdkwACUhPsBQMUXYWAh9lItUPQngmDVLkyikuNthTQoKW/jQGo0jHru8HdEu4X//t1T5tk5XxaJgFC42tF2K+WV6hKDH2cUKmP5zCBbUPkLBS1inEp2ZD5ObCSgYj0U2P62NRIyYF59KrQdi/g6tSLaotqsZFs9fLx9L5ev73mfKgdh/FxWs4nFTmf5LEZ06Yzfm6Uzw7R2XSWfnt5/oiSTSZJlu7W4SSUyEfBedwV3TEPMXNhz1OUhaRKG8wwmvk2uK+IITWWrDdK2pa1vxUVpDA=).

PS: `:style` is a shorthand for `v-bind:style` as [explained here](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind).

---

[`v-bind` for **CSS**](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css) (mixing `script` + `style`) is also a thing.
Here, you're only using `script` + `template` combo, so an interpolation is enough.